# Problems generate envelope special characters

Tags: java, soap

I have to create a SOAPMessage from a string.

My problem is that the string contains special characters and gives me an error when trying to generate the Envelope.

I have to create the envelope with special characters.

I only use the classes of java 1.7 and I need to use the classes of the code, I can not use another type of envelope.

This my code

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //We have a envelope with special characters
        String input = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"><car:Input xmlns:car=\"http://soap.sctinst.redsys.es/consumed/CARGAENTIDADES\"><list><obj><name>José Televisión</name></obj></list></car:Input></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();
        headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        headers.setHeader("Encoding", "UTF-8");

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        int n = bis.available();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
        bis.read(bytes, 0, n);

        //I specify the encoding 
        String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());

        //Create a new SOAPMessage 
        SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(headers, is);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(out);
        out.toString();
        //print the envelope and the especial characters are corrects
        System.out.println(out.toString());
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();

        //FAIL THIS LINE 
        //com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
        //GRAVE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();


        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        Source source = soapPart.getContent();
        //.... continue the code    
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error? Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

per XML standard there are 3 characters that must be XML encoded. Please take a look at the answer here:
[xml-or-php-or-someone-is-eating-my-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352578/xml-or-php-or-someone-is-eating-my-characters/46354159#46354159)

BTW: if by any chances there could be binary data it must be encoded as well. As Base64, Hexadecimal or anyhow else.

UPD: What special characters are you talking about?
Your example does not have any of them and it works fine. 
Please post message(s) from "Caused by:" part(s) of your exception.

`SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source` is a top message and says nothing useful.